# Issues building ivtools

Tags: macos, build, clang

I'm trying to install the ivtools vector graphics editor (http://ivtools.sourceforge.net/ivtools/index.html) on macOS big sur. I'm trying to build it from source and I keep running into the issue below

ld: library not found for -lIV

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm not entirely sure what the -lIV library is and can't find anything easily online. If anyone has done this before on macOS I'd appreciate some pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not finding the libIV library probably means this library was not successfully built.  If it had built successfully you would see these files:

```
./src/IV-common/DARWIN/libIV-common.dylib
./src/IV-common/DARWIN/libIV-common.2.0.4.dylib
./src/IV/DARWIN/libIV.2.0.4.dylib
./src/IV/DARWIN/libIV.dylib
```

If you can locate the error message in building libIV I can probably be of more help.